# C# raycast code not working with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hi so I wrote some code to create a raycast that follows the mouse position on the screen, I have the gun set up and I have the barrel down properly with a collider etc, but I keep getting the error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I just can't work out what the problem is, here's my code:

```
    void Update ()
    {
        if (gun.active) {
                    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {
                            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
                            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit ();
                            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "barrel") {
                                            Debug.Log ("Hit the Barrel");
                                            Destroy (hit.collider.gameObject);
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }

    }
```

Comment: On which line of code does the exception throw?

Comment: @hatchet it throws on the Ray ray = Camera.main line

Answer (score 4):

Your `Camera` is not tagged as `main` camera in the *Editor*.

That is why your code can't find it and thus why it throws an exception.